# Tables could not be fetched - Error loading schema content

Tags: mysql-workbench, workbench, kie-workbench, sql-workbench-j

I open workbench and connect to a local database on XAMPP and when open the connection the schema show the error message:

> "tables could not be fetched"

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the credentials that you are using are correct ?

Comment: Dear @LucaStucchi, I've approved your edit, but note that greetings, thank-you and other help-me message can be removed as well. And it's best to format messages with a `>`. See my subsequent edit.

Comment: My credentials are root and no password. I dont know why workbench cant fetch

Comment: That might be a bug that was solved in the upcomming 8.0.17 version.

Comment: SQL Workbench/J and MySQL Workench are two very different things. Which one are you really using?

Answer (score 22):

run this command on terminal

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Comment: Adding a bit of context to this command; the mysql_upgrade is a compatibility checker, it makes sure tables, privileges etc. is brought in line with the version of MySQL/MariaDB. Incompatibilities can happen when upgrading a major version and hence it's also recommended to run this command after an upgrade (hence the name!).

Answer (score 14):

Run this command on terminal

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql_upgrade
```

And as per the comment by @[jonathan-delean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5837967) , you might need to run this instead:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Comment: sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql_upgrade -u root -p

Comment: Why? What does it do? It does not fix it for me. I have this issue with a fresh install of latest 5.7.x, and a workbench of latest 8.0.x. It seems they are not compatible, or this latest workbench has an issue.

Answer (score 14):

For XAMPP, this worked for me - run this on terminal:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_upgrade
```

Disconnect then reconnect to your db.

Answer (score 2):

First, locate the directory of which Xampp is installed at.
In linux you can just type this in a terminal:

`whereis xampp`

In my case (btw I use arch, jk) it was located at /opt/lampp/bin . If you're using windows, you may find it under a different location, like in C:\Program Files\xampp\bin

Next, locate the file mysql_upgrade and execute it as an administrator or a sudo.
If you're using Linux:
`cd /opt/lampp/bin` then `sudo ./mysql_upgrade`

According to MySQL documentation:

> Each time you upgrade MySQL, you should execute mysql_upgrade, which
> looks for incompatibilities with the upgraded MySQL server: It
> upgrades the system tables in the mysql schema so that you can take
> advantage of new privileges or capabilities that might have been
> added. It upgrades the Performance Schema, INFORMATION_SCHEMA, and sys
> schema. It examines user schemas.

So I believe mysql_upgrade should resolve the problem. It worked for me before.

More on mysql_upgrade here:

[4.4.5 mysql_upgrade — Check and Upgrade MySQL Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-upgrade.html)

Answer (score 2):

for macOS users run this on terminal:
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql_upgrade
this worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

That's because the latest XAMPP use MariaDB and MYSQL Workbench is using MYSQL Database, so they are not fully compatible, raising that error for example.You can try to downgrade to some of the previous XAMPP versions.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS users:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql_upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I created another Connection in MySQL workbench, and the fetching problem for me was resloved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did have this problem today, the reason is:

```
Error Code: 1356 View 'test.xyz' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
```

After dropping those view (actually those views) the error was solved.

[image]

currently working with MySQL Workbench 8.0.28, and MySQL 8.0.28.

Answer (score 0):

See YouTube video: MySQL 8 - The message "Tables Could Not Be Fetched"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phi6o8B7kKI

Either a table or view or function used in code has been dropped; hence the "...could not be fetched".

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

> sudo mysql_upgrade --force

Answer (score 0):

As [@Brittany Layne Rapheal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2544839/brittany-layne-rapheal) says, with that command you can fix the issue, is also recommended to give execution privileges to that file:

So you should run first this command:

```
sudo chmod +x /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_upgrade
```

And then, this:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_upgrade --force
```

> `--force` is necessary because as the parameter says to force the update (Necessary)

Answer (score 0):

If you have create view table earlier and than renamed the table or any columns than you also have to change the name manually in view

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate cause for same error (invalid/broken SQL in views)**

There is an alternate cause for this error that has nothing to do with compatibility issues, not to mention mysql_upgrade is deprecated now. If you have altered table names and/or column names so that some of your views are now broken then you can get this error after MySQL is restarted. Fixing whats wrong in your views can solve the problem (deleting the views works if you're able to do that but obviously thats not possible in every use case...)