# Using XAMPP and Mysql Workbench together

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

There are some related posts to this but I still can't figure this out. I have a working install of XAMPP(latest version) and MySQL Workbench 8.0.17 installed. **I just want to be able to use Workbench with the MySQL that ships with the XAMPP install.**

In the latest version of XAMPP, it first sets an IP address before I can start apache and mysql. MySQL seems to be running on port 3307.

Here is the Workbench screen to make a new connection. XAMPP is running on localhost - should that be my hostname?

[image]

If I try a localhost or 127.0.0.1 hostname with port 3307 (where I think XAMPP's MySQL is) I get this popup alert. If I continue, I still don't see any of my databases listed on the main screen.

[image]

Comment: MySQL is normally on 3306

Comment: Those defaults look like they should work as they are

Comment: your error message looks like your xampp is shipped with an older version of  mysql. So the connection is established but mysql is not at least 5.6

Comment: This always happens. After I post a question I figure out something important. XAMPP ships with MariaDB which MySQL Workbench doesn't support. I am going to attempt to revert XAMPP to MySQL (not MariaDB) -  (@RiggsFolly - XAMPP appears to utilize 3307 for the DB)

Comment: For mariaDB, maybe they did so you can install MySQL and us it on 3306 without conflicts

Comment: @RiggsFolly - If I have MySQL running on port 3306 - how do I tell XAMPP to use that MySQL install? DO I just edit the my.cnf that XAMPP uses to point to the mysql install?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tables could not be fetched - Error loading schema content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564410/tables-could-not-be-fetched-error-loading-schema-content)

Answer (score 23):

This is the way I have used to connecting MySQL workbench to Xampp MySQL.

01) Click on the Plus icon.

[image: Click on plus icon]

02) Check the Xampp MySQL port number.

[image: Check the Xampp MySQL port number]

03)Type the connection name and check the port number with your Xampp MySql port number.

[image: Type the connection name and check the port number with your Xampp MySql port number]

04) Click on the "Continue Anyway" button.

[image: Click on the "Continue Anyway" button]

05) Then click on the "OK" button to save the connection.

[image: Then click on the "OK" button to save the connection]

06) Now you can see the connection you just created and click on it to connect to the MySQL database.

[image: Click the newly created connection]

07) Just try to run some SQL code to if properly connected to Xampp Mysql.

[image: Just try to run some SQL code]

Answer (score 1):

I finally find solution on mac:

Notice that XAMPP server works on virtue machine inside with debian system and MoriaDB, so if you'd like to run Mysql WorkBench on MacOS outside, you must not use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` as host name.

Please check your ip address of XAMPP on its panel `General` tab, mainly like `192.xxx.xxx.x`, **this is your host name!**

And if you disable or uninstall mysql in your system, you can safely use default **port 3306**, or if you must use both XAMPP and local version, modify one pls.

Then, when it comes to user part, **do not use root!** Please add a new user in phpMyAdmin with hostname `%`, or open XAMPP terminal and use mysql instructions.

After filling all those above, Mysql will be able to start (although with warning, you can ignore it).

Comment: This partially solved my problem, but now it turns out MySQL workbench and MariaDB don't get along, so while I'm able to see the DBs, I can't actually do anything with them and get an error "Tables could not be fetched - Error loading schema content". I'll add a new comment if I solve that issue

Answer (score 0):

The way I 'fixed' this issue was to install an older version of xampp (5.4x) which ships with mysql, not mariadb. Before the install, I dumped all my dbs into a file and then imported them again after the install. Through XAMPP/phpMyAdmin I could see the fresh database. I tried to connect with MySQL Workbench and walla!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu, run this command on terminal

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql_upgrade
```

and then follow @prasadgayan 's answer above.

Note: It is a slight chance that your mysql_upgrade be in some other directory. If that's the case, run it from that path.

Please comment, if something similar work for Windows as well.
Namaste

Reference: [Tables could not be fetched - Error loading schema content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62337218/10204932)

Answer (score 0):

Normally the issue is that one is trying to use root as a user, which is somewhat prohibited. So just create a new user with the correct access privileges granted. Here's a solution, that worked on a Mac (but should be relevant to most OS's).

Start the XAMPP stack. For simplicity, open phpMyAdmin, by default accessible via 127.0.0.1:80/phpmyadmin/ or 127.0.0.1:80/phpmyadmin/ locally.
In case needed, log in with the username *root* and an empty password field.
Create or pick a database for the user, to grant access to, for example "test_db". Enter the following in any SQL prompt (which normally can be executed by pressing [ctrl] + [enter]):

```
create user userbob identified by 'Pass2bob!';
grant all privileges on test_db.* to userbob@localhost;
```

Note your Xampp IP-adress which tends to default to "192.168.64.2" and port 3306. Now you should be able to access that database.

I tested the connection with some PHP-code, which I included here and might come handy for someone. 3306 is default as MySQL/Maria the database port, but I left it here in case someone, sometime, have to use a different port.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("192.168.64.2","userbob","Pass2bob!","test_db", 3306);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }
?>
```